# iWork purchasing options

Tags: mac-appstore, iwork

I purchased Pages, Keynote, and Numbers for my Mac Mini running Lion, but they're not showing up as purchased in the App Store with my usual Apple ID. They don't appear to be registered. I'm trying to find out how I bought them, since I have a new MacBook Air with Mountain Lion and I don't want to pay twice if I can help it. They might have been downloaded outside of the App Store. How do I trace my purchase and find out what I'm entitled to?

If I have to purchase these three again, is the App Store the best method from now on?

Answer (score 3):

You purchased them from the Mac App Store, and they don't show up in your Purchased list? That's odd. I'd contact Apple's support team and get them to fix it. However, if you bought them outside the Mac App Store - back when the suite was sold on a DVD - then *I think* you can get updates anyway. In either case, contact Apple.